# Stash, template partials and CE_image

Tags: stash, ce-image, template-partials

So I have my content that I put on my template article.html via the EE-publishform where I also get to choose wether to use layouts 'normal' or ' wide'.
The size of the images varies depending on wich layout I use. CE_image is what I use to resize images.

### problem

What I cant figure out is how to let CE_image do its work on the layout-template instead of on the article-template. Or if I could put the CE_image-tags on the article-template and then let the layout-templates insert apropriate values to size, crop and quality variables.

### disclaimer

I realize Stash is a genuinly complex and competent addon and the solution to my problem is probably right there in the Stash documentation. I have read it over and over and tried things over and over but I never seem to hit the keys in the right order.
So I am very ready for some advice on this matter.

Thanks
/David

#### content

- title
- body
- images (matrix-field)

  - img-1
  - img-2
  - img-3

#### Templates

#### Article

> {exp:channel:entries channel="archive" limit="1" url_title="{segment_2}"}
>
> {embed="_layouts/{f-archive-layout}"}
>
> {exp:stash:set name="title"}
>         {title}
>     {/exp:stash:set}
>
> {exp:stash:set name="content"}
>         {f-body}
>     {/exp:stash:set}
>
> {exp:stash:set name="images"}
>         {f-archive-images}
>             
>                 {exp:ce_img:pair src="{f-archive-images-image}" width="400" crop="yes" quality="80"}
>                     
>                 {/exp:ce_img:pair}
>             
>         {/f-archive-images}
>     {/exp:stash:set}
>
> {/exp:channel:entries}

#### Layouts

#### normal

[image: normal template]

#### wide

[image: wide template]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd be better off just 'stashing' the image urls and using the CE Image tag from within the layout.

Article

```
{f-archive-images}
  {exp:stash:set_list name="images"}
    {stash:url}{f-archive-images-image}{/stash:url}
  {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/f-archive-images}
```

Layout

```
First image:
{exp:stash:get_list name="images" limit="1"}
  {exp:ce_img:single src="{url}" width="400" crop="yes"}
{/exp:stash:get_list}

Second and third images:
{exp:stash:get_list name="images" offset="1" limit="2"}
  {exp:ce_img:single src="{url}" width="400" crop="yes"}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The point is that you are trying to keep your presentation separate. The CE Image tag, to me, is a presentational tag. You just need to get the image url to the layout. The above is one way to do it.

You could also use three separate `{exp:stash:set name="image_x"}{/exp:stash:set}` tags. Whatever you find that works.

Comment: Ah, it _was_ the list-thingy! thanks a lot!